# Application crashing when trying to store data on my database

Tags: android

My application is giving the following `NullPointerException`when I click on a button to store data into the database.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: neoxsoft.com.taxmukti, PID: 28055 java.lang.NullPointerException
at neoxsoft.com.taxmukti.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:50)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4452)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18451)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5421)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:979)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method
```

Here is my code:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText fnm_et,lnm_et,eid_et,contact_et,pass_et,repass_et;
Button submit_btn,log_btn;
StoreData sd;
DataBaseService db=new DataBaseService(this);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    fnm_et= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fnm_et);
    lnm_et= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lnm_et);
    eid_et= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eid_et);
    contact_et= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contact_et);
    pass_et= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass_et);
    repass_et= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.repass_et);

    submit_btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_btn);
    log_btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.log_btn);

    submit_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                String fname= fnm_et.getText().toString();
                String lname=lnm_et.getText().toString();
                String contact=contact_et.getText().toString();
                String mail=eid_et.getText().toString();
                String pass=pass_et.getText().toString();
                String repass=repass_et.getText().toString();
                Log.d("log1","getAlltext");

                sd.setF_name(fname);
                sd.setL_name(lname);
                sd.setMob_number(contact);
                sd.setE_mail(mail);
                sd.setUser_pass(pass);
                sd.setUser_repass(repass);
                Log.d("log2", "setAlltext");

                db.insertData(sd);
                Intent intent=new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                RegisterActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });

    log_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            RegisterActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}

> I initialized all component

```
fnm_et= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fnm_et);
    lnm_et= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lnm_et);
    eid_et= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eid_et);
    contact_et= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contact_et);
    pass_et= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass_et);
    repass_et= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.repass_et);

    submit_btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_btn);
    log_btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.log_btn);
```

Comment: Show your code in ``RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:50)``

Comment: Post the onClick code at least

Comment: post your code activity

Comment: Which statement is in line `50`? Are you sure that `sd` (whatever that is) and `db` are initialized?

Comment: you need to add TextView noData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noData);

Comment: One of your EditText has not been initiated, almost sure. Check that out. A NPE getting the text on an EditText points to that...

Comment: A null pointer exception usually happens when you set variable equal to something that doesn't exist. This could be because you haven't initialized that thing or simply mispelled it. Use breakpoints to help you figure out which line of code is causing your app to crash. If you're not familiar with breakpoints, I highly suggest you look them up. They are essential to debugging runtime errors like this. Good luck!

Comment: yes I initialized it... StoreData sd;
    DataBaseService db=new DataBaseService(this);

Comment: post java code @sikandar

Comment: In case of StoreData you are not initializing, if that is all the code you have...

Comment: Debug your code line by line to find out which variable that is not initialized (is null) which causes this error.

Comment: What does `sd` represent? Are you sure all your `EditText`s are initialized?

Comment: Definitely, sd is null. Initialize it in the proper way, and your code will work.

Comment: Guys I posted entire code of RegisterActivity.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sd variable is null, and is throwing the NPE. Initialize it.

Comment: u r rigth when I write `StoreData sd=new StoreData();` error is gone thank you